# Extra symbols on LCD

Tags: arduino, lcd

I am trying to display the readings from a laser rangefinder onto an LCD. I am able to display the serial on it along with "cm" but it keeps adding two symbols that appear to be Chinese. This is my first project using Arduino, can someone help me?

```cpp
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

/**
 * LIDARLite I2C Example
 * Author: Garmin
 * Modified by: Shawn Hymel (SparkFun Electronics)
 * Date: June 29, 2017
 * 
 * Read distance from LIDAR-Lite v3 over I2C
 * 
 * See the Operation Manual for wiring diagrams and more information:
 * http://static.garmin.com/pumac/LIDAR_Lite_v3_Operation_Manual_and_Technical_Specifications.pdf
 */

#include <Wire.h>
#include <LIDARLite.h>


const int rs = 12, en = 11, d4 = 5, d5 = 4, d6 = 3, d7 = 2;
LiquidCrystal lcd(rs, en, d4, d5, d6, d7);
// Globals
LIDARLite lidarLite;
int cal_cnt = 0;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600); // Initialize serial connection to display distance readings

  lidarLite.begin(0, true); // Set configuration to default and I2C to 400 kHz
  lidarLite.configure(0); // Change this number to try out alternate configurations


  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  // initialize the serial communications:
}

void loop()
{
  int dist;

  // At the beginning of every 100 readings,
  // take a measurement with receiver bias correction
  if ( cal_cnt == 0 ) {
    dist = lidarLite.distance();      // With bias correction
  } else {
    dist = lidarLite.distance(false); // Without bias correction
  }

  // Increment reading counter
  cal_cnt++;
  cal_cnt = cal_cnt % 100;

  // Display distance
  Serial.print(dist);
  Serial.println(" cm");

  delay(100);

    // when characters arrive over the serial port...
  if (Serial.available()) { 
    // wait a bit for the entire message to arrive
    delay(100);
    // clear the screen
    lcd.clear();
    // read all the available characters
    while (Serial.available() > 0) {
      // display each character to the LCD
      lcd.write(Serial.read());
    }
  }

  delay(100);
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.println(dist);
  lcd.println(" cm");

}
```

It should just display     (measurement) cm     on the LCD.
Instead I keep getting 218-- cm--,   -- being the two Chinese symbols.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be showing the carriage return and newline characters.

Replace `println` with `print`.